# pH of water on paper vs meter

Tags: water, ph

We have both a professional (lab) pH meter, and several different version of lab grade pH paper, but are experiencing a very weird phenomenon. We have calibrated all the papers against standards, and they work fine. (And of course our meter is regularly calibrated.) However, when we use the meter to measure the pH of various plain waters (e.g., de-ionized vs. tap) we get consistent readings ranging from 4 to 10 (for different sources), but the pH papers never register anything outside of ~6 for any of these waters. Our tap water, for example, reads 10 on the meter and 6 on the paper. (dry paper reads about 6 -- it's a bit hard to tell whether it's changing at all in the water, because, of course, just wetting it makes it look slightly different, but it's definitely not changing substantially.) Whereas the same paper reads perfectly well in various standards between 2 and 12!) Any idea what might be going on here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure how one calibrates indicator paper against standards, but what do pH-meter and paper show for common *fresh buffer* standards, say, for pH 4.00 and 9.18? Can you attach the photo of the paper strips before and after the measurement, the model of your pH-meter, and the procedure for paper testing?

Comment: TL;DR: under proper conditions I'd trust the pH-meter, not the paper. Indicator itself needs to participate in acid-base reaction and this consumes dissolved alkali transferred to the strip. Considering that a very small amount of the measured solution gets on the paper, the amount of alkali might be comparable to the amount of the indicator on the paper, thus lowering the readings towards lower pH values. Also, pH paper itself possess small buffer capacity, and, since it has a *mix* of indicators to make it universal, it has several non-specific pH regions, but this depends on manufacturer.